# Quickly solve math functions with large values (for graph)

Tags: c#, math, graph

I'm looking for a way to quickly get the results for a mathematical equation. Take "0.5 * sin(x) + 3" for example. The Google calculator can easily give me an exact result for HUGE values, but my C# application will stutter when drawing a graph in high value ranges or even give me an overflow. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how huge? `double` should be enough for most applications....

Comment: The problem is not that it wont work, but I have a graph which is 500px in width, and so every time a MouseMove occurs, I need to recalculate the values. And calculating the above function 500 times for values up to 1000000 wont work.

Comment: Do note that MouseMove occurs a lot more often than you may expect. Maybe you can measure the distance and only re-calculate after a minimum distance and/or timespan..

Comment: @NikxDa Why do you even recalculate on every mouse action instead of re-drawing already calculated values? And I still don't get why it does not work

Comment: Of course the formula calls for avoiding huge values of x as they only will loose precision; when they grow over, say, 1000*Pi simply reduce them!

Comment: Sorry, this was my fault - I'm using MouseMove to drag the canvas, and then I recalculate. I will try storing the calculated values and reuse them.